# Bootstrap: Not able to make use of full height for my empty content columns

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, asp.net-mvc-5

I am very new to web development and as new to using bootstrap. I have been trying to create a very page of this type:

```
---------------------------------------
Nav bar
---------------------------------------
             Search bar
---------------------------------------
col1                        |col2
                            |
                            |
                            |
                            |
                            |
                            |
                            |
                            |
                            |
                            |
                            |
                            |
----------------------------------------
```

The col1 and col2 i want to be utilising all the leftover height of the page (after search and nav bar). But whatever I tried, I could do it. Its always taking the height of the content when filled in. I would also like scroll bars to appear when content is more than what can fit in the page length, but minimum height should be the max height possible. Following is the web page code I am using.

```
@{

    ViewBag.Title = "Home";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<style>

    .top-buffer { margin-top:3%; }

    body,html{
        height:100%;

    }
     #outer {
        position: relative;
    }
    #outer a {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
    #outer input {
         text-indent: 16px;
    }

    .left-dotted-border{
        border-left: 1px dotted  #333;
    }

    .min-content-height{
        min-height:100%;
    }
     #dashboard-data {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    background: red;
    display: block;
}

}

</style>
<div class="container" id="searchBar" style="min-height:100%">
    <div class="row top-buffer">
        <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
            <form class="form-inline" role="form" id="searchParamters">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="search">Search</label>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="sr-only" for="keyword"></label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="keyword" placeholder="Enter keywords">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="tag-tree">under</label>
                </div>

                <div id="outer"class="form-group">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="alert('Show tag tree')"><img src="~/Content/img/Hierarchy.png" style="width:34px; height:34px"></a>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tag" placeholder="  tag">

                </div>


                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>


</div>
<hr size="2" />

<div id="dashboard-data" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8 min-content-height" style="min-height:100%">
            <div>My Content</div>

        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 left-dotted-border size" style="min-height:100%">
            Recommended content

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Version used: Bootstrap v3.3.1, ASP.NET MVC 5

Comment: You should post HTML code too, and maybe creating a JsFiddle, in order to allow us to do some tests :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want to give the columns viewport height:

```
height: 100vh;
```

Learn more about [vh on CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/).